# npm link not working as expected

Tags: node.js, npm

I have 3 local modules "web", "presentation" and "repository" in 3 different directories. Each module has a package.json with name property as "myproject-web", "myproject-presentation" and "myproject-repository".

i am trying to link repository -> web and presentation -> web. so i tried this:

```
cd ./presentation
npm link
cd ../repository
npm link
cd ../web
npm link myproject-presentation
npm link myproject-repository
```

Both last commands are failing as NPM is looking for "myproject-..." in npm registry and this is the error i get

```
npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on http://registry.npmjs.org/myproject-repository
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 'myproject-repository' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
```

Please note, i didn't get any error while running 'npm link' on dependent directories (presentation and web). It returned successfully with the following :

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/myproject-presentation -> /Users/koder/projects/test/myproject-presentation

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/myproject-repository -> /Users/koder/projects/test/myproject-repository
```

I am following this [blog post as reference](http://justjs.com/posts/npm-link-developing-your-own-npm-modules-without-tears)

**Solved: Please see my own answer:**

```
Realised what i am doing wrong. I forgot to create a .npmrc file in "repository" and "presentation" folder step the blog post mentioned.

npm link is working as expected
```

Answer (score 0):

Realised what i am doing wrong. I forgot to create a .npmrc file in "repository" and "presentation" folder step the blog post mentioned.

npm link is working as expected